# How to create button based chatbot

Tags: python, networkx, flowchart, rasa

I have created a chatbot using **RASA** to work with free text and it is working fine. As per my new requirement i need to build button based chatbot which should follow flowchart kind of structure. I don't know how to do that what i thought is to convert the flowchart into graph data structure using **networkx** but i am not sure whether it has that capability. I did search but most of the examples are using dialogue or chat fuel. Can i do it using networkx.
Please help.

Comment: I have also the same kind of requirement. Have searched many things in google but still no luck, If you achieve this can you share some example of code how can we actually use button-based workflow with rasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can.

You just need each button to point to another intent. The payload of each button should point have the `/intent_value` as its payload and this will cause the NLU to skip evaluation and simply predict the intent. Then you can just bind a trigger to the intent or use the `utter_` method.

Hope that helps.